# htaccess redirect with full url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect from one domain to another using htaccess?

```
RewriteRule http://www.google.com/old-route http://www.google.com/new-route [R=301,L]
RewriteRule https://www.google.com/old-route https://www.google.com/new-route [R=301,L]
```

If not, how would you do the redirect for multiple domains on one project?

Comment: You're showing same `www.google.com` domain in source and target URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by using rewriteConditions: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond

Something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1
RewriteRule ^old-route$ https://www.site1alt.com/new-route [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

For one Domain use.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.google\.com/old-route$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/new-route [R=301,L]
```

For redirecting everything you could use this.

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.google.com/new-route
```

Answer (score 1):

Given https://www.example.com/foobar the single `%{HTTP_HOST}` as used in the other answers only looks for `www.example.com`, not taking the following path into account. So these answers were not working for me. Maybe something changed during Apache versions. What worked for me was to concatenate `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` to be checked.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www\.example\.com/foo\.html$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www\.example\.com/bar\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/foobar [R=301,L]
```

---

Check out this nice [Mod_Rewrite Variables Cheatsheet](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet/) for an overview of many available mod_rewrite variables.